# Convert datetime object to a String of date only in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I see a lot on converting a date string to an `datetime` object in Python, but I want to go the other way.
I've got

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 23, 0, 0)
```

and I would like to convert it to string like `'2/23/2012'`.

Answer (score 760, accepted):

You can use [strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) to help you format your date.

E.g.,

```
import datetime
t = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 23, 0, 0)
t.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

will yield:

```
'02/23/2012'
```

More information about formatting see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Very useful for `DateTimeField` or `DateField` in django.  Thanks

Comment: use `t = datetime.datetime.now()` to use current date

Comment: As far as I can tell from the docs there is no way to return a non-zero padded date ie '2/23/2012'.

Comment: @Ron Kalian Non-zero padded: `t.strftime('%-m/%-d/%-y')`

Comment: f-strings are a lot nicer if you're on python 3.6+. See answer below

Answer (score 306):

`date` and `datetime` objects (and `time` as well) support a [mini-language to specify output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), and there are two ways to access it:

- [direct method call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime): `dt.strftime('format here')`
- [format method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) (python 2.6+): `'{:format here}'.format(dt)`
- [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) (python 3.6+): `f'{dt:format here}'`

So your example could look like:

- `dt.strftime('The date is %b %d, %Y')`
- `'The date is {:%b %d, %Y}'.format(dt)`
- `f'The date is {dt:%b %d, %Y}'`

In all three cases the output is:

> The date is Feb 23, 2012

For completeness' sake: you can also directly access the attributes of the object, but then you only get the numbers:

```
'The date is %s/%s/%s' % (dt.month, dt.day, dt.year)
# The date is 02/23/2012
```

The time taken to learn the mini-language is worth it.

---

For reference, here are the codes used in the mini-language:

- `%a`  Weekday as locale’s abbreviated name.
- `%A`  Weekday as locale’s full name.
- `%w`  Weekday as a decimal number, where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday.
- `%d`  Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
- `%b`  Month as locale’s abbreviated name.
- `%B`  Month as locale’s full name.
- `%m`  Month as a zero-padded decimal number.  01, ..., 12
- `%y`  Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.   00, ..., 99
- `%Y`  Year with century as a decimal number.  1970, 1988, 2001, 2013
- `%H`  Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.   00, ..., 23
- `%I`  Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.   01, ..., 12
- `%p`  Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM.
- `%M`  Minute as a zero-padded decimal number.     00, ..., 59
- `%S`  Second as a zero-padded decimal number.     00, ..., 59
- `%f`  Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded on the left.   000000, ..., 999999
- `%z`  UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM  (empty if naive), +0000, -0400, +1030
- `%Z`  Time zone name      (empty if naive), UTC, EST, CST
- `%j`  Day of the year as a zero-padded decimal number.    001, ..., 366
- `%U`  Week number of the year (Sunday is the first) as a zero padded decimal number.
- `%W`  Week number of the year (Monday is first) as a decimal number.
- `%c`  Locale’s appropriate date and time representation.
- `%x`  Locale’s appropriate date representation.
- `%X`  Locale’s appropriate time representation.
- `%%`  A literal '%' character.

Comment: Sexiest version of the answer here

Comment: I think we have different interpretations of what makes "sexy".  :-)

Answer (score 72):

Another option:

```
import datetime
now=datetime.datetime.now()
now.isoformat()
# ouptut --> '2016-03-09T08:18:20.860968'
```

Comment: Though the question is about getting "date only", I came for ^this, so thanks. Also, to get a bit more humane string: `datetime.datetime.now().ctime()` ==> `'Wed Sep  4 13:12:39 2019'`

Answer (score 24):

If you are looking for a simple way of `datetime` to string conversion and can omit the format. You can convert `datetime` object to `str` and then use array slicing.

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: now = datetime.now()

In [3]: str(now)
Out[3]: '2019-04-26 18:03:50.941332'

In [5]: str(now)[:10]
Out[5]: '2019-04-26'

In [6]: str(now)[:19]
Out[6]: '2019-04-26 18:03:50'
```

But note the following thing. If other solutions will rise an `AttributeError` when the variable is `None` in this case you will receive a `'None'` string.

```
In [9]: str(None)[:19]
Out[9]: 'None'
```

Comment: Python has more consistent methods to convert Datetime from object to string, like strftime. Slices will depend on length from your string what is prone to error

Answer (score 17):

You can easly convert the datetime to string in this way:

```py
from datetime import datetime

date_time = datetime(2012, 2, 23, 0, 0)
date = date_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print("date: %s" % date)
```

These are some of the patterns that you can use to convert datetime to string:

[image: datetime to string patterns]

For better understanding, you can take a look at this article on [how to convert strings to datetime and datetime to string in Python](https://www.polynique.com/programming-languages/python-string-to-datetime-and-datetime-to-string/) or the [official `strftime` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Answer (score 15):

You could use simple string formatting methods:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 23, 0, 0)
>>> '{0.month}/{0.day}/{0.year}'.format(dt)
'2/23/2012'
>>> '%s/%s/%s' % (dt.month, dt.day, dt.year)
'2/23/2012'
```

Comment: similarly, you can do something like `'{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M}'.format(datetime(2001, 2, 3, 4, 5))`. See more at pyformat.info

Answer (score 12):

[**`type-specific formatting`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) can be used as well:

```
t = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 23, 0, 0)
"{:%m/%d/%Y}".format(t)
```

Output:

```
'02/23/2012'
```

Answer (score 11):

The sexiest version by far is with format strings.

```py
from datetime import datetime

print(f'{datetime.today():%Y-%m-%d}')
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want the time as well, just go with

```
datetime.datetime.now().__str__()
```

Prints `2019-07-11 19:36:31.118766` in console for me

Answer (score 4):

You can convert datetime to string.

```
published_at = "{}".format(self.published_at)
```

Comment: Or, using the f-string syntax: `published_at = f"{self.published_at}"`

Answer (score 4):

```py
end_date = "2021-04-18 16:00:00"
end_date_string = end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(end_date_string)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to convert a datetime object into a string by working directly with the components of the datetime object.

```
from datetime import date  

myDate = date.today()    
#print(myDate) would output 2017-05-23 because that is today
#reassign the myDate variable to myDate = myDate.month 
#then you could print(myDate.month) and you would get 5 as an integer
dateStr = str(myDate.month)+ "/" + str(myDate.day) + "/" + str(myDate.year)    
# myDate.month is equal to 5 as an integer, i use str() to change it to a 
# string I add(+)the "/" so now I have "5/" then myDate.day is 23 as
# an integer i change it to a string with str() and it is added to the "5/"   
# to get "5/23" and then I add another "/" now we have "5/23/" next is the 
# year which is 2017 as an integer, I use the function str() to change it to 
# a string and add it to the rest of the string.  Now we have "5/23/2017" as 
# a string. The final line prints the string.

print(dateStr)
```

Output --> 5/23/2017

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation, `str.join`, can be used to build the string.

```
d = datetime.now()
'/'.join(str(x) for x in (d.month, d.day, d.year))
'3/7/2016'
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach to **how far from now**

- support different languages by passing in param `li`, a list corresponding timestamp.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser

t1 = parser.parse("Tue May 26 15:14:45 2021")
t2 = parser.parse("Tue May 26 15:9:45 2021")
# 5min
t3 = parser.parse("Tue May 26 11:14:45 2021")
# 4h
t4 = parser.parse("Tue May 26 11:9:45 2021")
# 1day
t6 = parser.parse("Tue May 25 11:14:45 2021")
# 1day4h
t7 = parser.parse("Tue May 25 11:9:45 2021")
# 1day4h5min
t8 = parser.parse("Tue May 19 11:9:45 2021")
# 1w
t9 = parser.parse("Tue Apr 26 11:14:45 2021")
# 1m
t10 = parser.parse("Tue Oct 08 06:00:20 2019") 
# 1y7m, 19m
t11 = parser.parse("Tue Jan 08 00:00:00 2019") 
# 2y4m, 28m


# create: date of object creation
# now: time now
# li: a list of string indicate time (in any language)
# lst: suffix (in any language)
# long: display length
def howLongAgo(create, now, li, lst, long=2):
    dif = create - now
    print(dif.days)
    sec = dif.days * 24 * 60 * 60 + dif.seconds
    minute = sec // 60
    sec %= 60
    hour = minute // 60
    minute %= 60
    day = hour // 24
    hour %= 24
    week = day // 7
    day %= 7
    month = (week * 7) // 30
    week %= 30
    year = month // 12
    month %= 12
    s = []
    for ii, tt in enumerate([sec, minute, hour, day, week, month, year]):
        ss = li[ii]
        if tt != 0:
            if tt == 1:
                s.append(str(tt) + ss)
            else:
                s.append(str(tt) + ss + 's')

    return ' '.join(list(reversed(s))[:long]) + ' ' + lst



t = howLongAgo(t1, t11, [
    'second', 
    'minute',
    'hour', 
    'day',
    'week', 
    'month',
    'year',
], 'ago')
print(t)
# 2years 4months ago
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method to insert dates to JSON object

```
my_json_string = json.dumps({'date_of_birth': '''{}'''.format(date_of_birth)})
```