# Rest Api timestamp string python

Tags: api, date, python-3.x, timestamp

i get from the api following string for date and time

```
t = "2015-02-06T10:11:02.900Z"
```

I need only the date in this format: DD.MM.YYYY
This is what i tried:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
```

And this is the error i get:

> ValueError: time data '2015-02-06T10:11:02.900Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'

Answer (score 1):

You've used the incorrect directive: `'%z'` doesn't match `Z` (`'%z'` matches a numeric utc offset such as `'+0200'`). See [How to parse ISO formatted date in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/4279) Just replace `%z` with `Z` in your case:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.strptime("2015-02-06T10:11:02.900Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 6, 10, 11, 2, 900000)
```

To get DD.MM.YYYY, you could use `.strftime()` method. See [Convert datetime object to a String of date only in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10624937/4279):

```
>>> d.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
'06.02.2015'
```

Answer (score 0):

Take only the date part of the string:

```
>>> datetime.strptime(t.split('T')[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 6, 0, 0)
```

To get `DD.MM.YYYY` format result, use [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
>>> datetime.strptime(t.split('T')[0], "%Y-%m-%d").strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
'06.02.2015'
```