# How to convert string to datetime object in python for years 2070 and above?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, datetime

While I was trying to convert String into datetime , I encountered the following:

```
S='30-01-50'
datetime.datetime.str 
>>datetime.date(2050, 1, 30)
```

However

```
S='30-01-70'
datetime.datetime.strptime(S,"%d-%m-%y").date()
>>datetime.date(1970, 1, 30)
```

Why not 2070 ?. How does one perform arithmetic on such datetime values?

Comment: Isn't the problem here that your string isn't unambiguous? Python supports years up to 9999, but 1970 is *what you should get* for only 70. Where is the input coming from, and why can't it include the full year?

Comment: I tried S='30-01-1970' , I threw the error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 70

Comment: You didn't change the pattern from %y to %Y. Why?

Comment: Ooh! Din't know that , its working now . Thanks! .But technically how are they different from each other?

Answer (score 0):

For a quick reference, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35780962/208880).

Quick answer:  do not use two-digit years, use four-digit years and the `%Y` specifier.