# removing datetime.datetime from a list in python

Tags: python, xml, matplotlib

I'm attempting to get 2 different elements from an XML file, I'm trying to print them as the x and y on a scatter plot, I can manage to get both the elements but when I plot them it only uses one of the dates to plot the other elements. I'm using the below code to get a weather HTML and save it as an XML.

```
        url = "http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat=52.41616;lon=-4.064598"
        response = requests.get(url)
        xml_text=response.text
        weather= bs4.BeautifulSoup(xml_text, "xml")
        f = open('file.xml', "w")
        f.write(weather.prettify())
        f.close()
```

I'm then trying to get the time ('from') element and the ('windSpeed' > 'mps') element and attribute. I'm then trying to plot it as an x and y on a scatter plot.

```
 with open ('file.xml') as file:
     soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(file, "xml")
     times = soup.find_all("time")
     windspeed = soup.select("windSpeed")
     form = ("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
     x = []
     y = []
     for element in times:
         time = element.get("from")
         t = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, form)
         x.append(t)
     for mps in windspeed:
         speed = mps.get("mps")
         y.append(speed)
     plt.scatter(x, y)         
     plt.show()
```

I'm trying to make 2 lists from 2 loops, and then read them as the x and y, but when I run it it gives the error;
    raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")
ValueError: x and y must be the same size

I'm assuming it's because it prints the list as datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 22, 21, 0), how do I remove the datetime.datetime from the list.

I know there's probably a simple way of fixing it, any ideas would be great, you people here on stack are helping me a lot with learning to code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make two lists one containing x-axis values and other with y-axis values and pass to scatter function

> plt.scatter(list1, list2);

Comment: I attempted to use 2 lists but it's throwing the error I've put in the question, any ideas?

Comment: just dont put `plt.scatter(x,y) and plt.show()` in for loop.

Comment: @M.Man what is `t` in `x.append(t)`? it might also causing you error

Comment: it should read, 't = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, form)' , the error at the end is ValueError("x and y must be the same size")

Comment: plz make these twwo statement outside the for loop `plt.scatter(x,y) and plt.show()`. By putting them inside loop the size of both list is not same in first iteration and hence it throws error.

Comment: Even outside the loop it still throws the error, the x list is being printed with datetime.datetime infront of every iteration.

Comment: I think either `t` is containing a list or the number of elements in both x and y list are different. check them these two issues.

Comment: refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624937/convert-datetime-object-to-a-string-of-date-only-in-python) and connvet `t` before appending to list x

Comment: I've realised it's not the format it's the way I've got the data that is the problem, the x has 155 and the y only has 50, so I need to go back figure out how to select only "from" elements with "windSpeed" elements. I appreciate the help anyway.

Comment: thanks @M.Man and make sure you always get pair of data i.e. time corresponding to windspeed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use **lxml** for analysing xml because it gives you the ability to use xpath expressions which can make life much easier. In this case, not every time entry contains a windSpeed entry; therefore, it's essential to identify the windSpeed entries first then to get the associated times. This code does that. There are two little problems I usually encounter: (1) I still need to 'play' with xpath to get it right; (2) Sometimes I get a list when I expect a singleton which is why there's a '[0]' in the code. I find it's better to build the code interactively.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> XML = open('file.xml')
>>> tree = etree.parse(XML)
>>> for count, windSpeeds in enumerate(tree.xpath('//windSpeed')):
...     windSpeeds.attrib['mps'], windSpeeds.xpath('../..')[0].attrib['from']
...     if count>5:
...         break
...     
('3.9', '2016-12-29T18:00:00Z')
('4.8', '2016-12-29T21:00:00Z')
('5.0', '2016-12-30T00:00:00Z')
('4.5', '2016-12-30T03:00:00Z')
('4.1', '2016-12-30T06:00:00Z')
('3.8', '2016-12-30T09:00:00Z')
('4.4', '2016-12-30T12:00:00Z')
```