# Returning strings instead of digits with datetime.strptime

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, strptime

With the following code:

```
current_date = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
dates.append(current_date)
```

I want to return the dates in the string format (i.e. `"Jan 2014"`) but it's returning the dates in the original format as `"2014-01-01"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert datetime object to a String of date only in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624937/convert-datetime-object-to-a-string-of-date-only-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

The default string representation of a [`date`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#date-objects) object is a string representing the date in ISO 8601 format, `'YYYY-MM-DD'`. To represent dates in other format, use [`date.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime), e.g.:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.today().strftime('%b %d, %Y')
'Sep 19, 2017'
```

For a complete list of formatting directives, see [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).