# How can I transform a datetime into a string to insert in xml tag (python, xml and psql)?

Tags: python, xml, datetime, serialization, psql

I'm developing a script in python2 to generate a xml file with information that is in a database (psql database), but I get the following error:

> Cannot serialize datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 4, 23, 5) (type datetime)

The code is the following:

```
for row in rows:
    Jobs = ET.SubElement(JobList, 'Jobs')
    ........
    scheduledTime.text = row[7]
    startTime.text = row[8]
    endTime.text = row[9]
    ........
    myJobList = ET.tostring(JobList)
```

and the data returned by the fetchall of the query is:

```
(3090, 'Backup-Local.2018-02-04_23.05.00_57', 'Backup-Local',
 'B', 'F', 1, 'T', datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 4, 23, 5),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 4, 23, 5, 2), 
 datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 4, 23, 5, 20), 
 datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 4, 23, 5, 20), 
 1517785520L, 349, 1515088289, 488, 386893432L, 
 397505297L, 0, 0, 2, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 'File')
```

I want to know how can I 'translate' the datetime returned to a string or if exists a datetime type in xml?!?!

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624937/convert-datetime-object-to-a-string-of-date-only-in-python

Comment: Sumit jha, i tried to search and didn't find anything... only json datetime erros... but ty :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When searching for ur error message at google i find this post:

[How to overcome "datetime.datetime not JSON serializable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable)

there one is recommended to use function isoformat()for convertion. But there is a bright further discussion worth to be read.

Comment: i found it too, but it applys to json with dump() and i wanted something to xml not json!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `datetime` modules `strftime` method to convert datetime object to string object.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
s = (3090, 'Backup-Local.2018-02-04_23.05.00_57', 'Backup-Local',
 'B', 'F', 1, 'T', datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 4, 23, 5),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 4, 23, 5, 2), 
 datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 4, 23, 5, 20), 
 datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 4, 23, 5, 20), 
 1517785520L, 349, 1515088289, 488, 386893432L, 
 397505297L, 0, 0, 2, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 'File')

res = []
for i in s:
    if isinstance(i, datetime.datetime):
        res.append(i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))    #Convert datetime to string.
    else:
        res.append(i) 

print(res)
print(tuple(res))
```

**Output:**

```
[3090, 'Backup-Local.2018-02-04_23.05.00_57', 'Backup-Local', 'B', 'F', 1, 'T', '2018-02-04 23:05:00', '2018-02-04 23:05:02', '2018-02-04 23:05:20', '2018-02-04 23:05:20', 1517785520L, 349, 1515088289, 488, 386893432L, 397505297L, 0, 0, 2, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 'File']

(3090, 'Backup-Local.2018-02-04_23.05.00_57', 'Backup-Local', 'B', 'F', 1, 'T', '2018-02-04 23:05:00', '2018-02-04 23:05:02', '2018-02-04 23:05:20', '2018-02-04 23:05:20', 1517785520L, 349, 1515088289, 488, 386893432L, 397505297L, 0, 0, 2, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 'File')
```