# Converting to manipulatable datetime format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a date value `20130312` and I would like to convert it into a format like `2013-03-12` or a similar format

I've tried looking into the `datetime` library but could not find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: datetime.strptime, datetime.strftime

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10624968/1189040

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.strptime('20130312', '%Y%m%d'))
```

For info on the pattern used, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).