# How do I find date for with hours?

Tags: python

In python, I want to find the date and time and put it inside of a string.

I have tried this:

example = datetime.datetime.now()

print(example)

However it returns the date with the miliseconds. What do I do if i don't want the miliseconds included. Just the date and time formatted like this:

YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime

Comment: Nothing came up when you searched for "Python format datetime"?

Comment: Duplicate? [Convert datetime object to a String of date only in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624937/convert-datetime-object-to-a-string-of-date-only-in-python)

Comment: example.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import datetime
example = datetime.datetime.now()
print(example.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the datetime output using this:

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

This will give you Hours:Minutes:Seconds

To get the format as per your requirements use:

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

This will give you date time in **YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:0**0 format **without milliseconds**.

My output: 2019-11-04 22:09:06

To see more directives: [Link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-get-min-seconds-and-milliseconds-from-datetime-now-in-Python)

Link says:

> You can get the formatted date and time using strftime function. It
>   accepts a format string that you can use to get your desired output

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question corretly, somethinig like this should work for you.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
date = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
print("date:",date)
```

It came from [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime). There are other formatting examples in that post.

Answer (score 0):

Datetime's strftime functionality does exactly what you're looking for.

There is some overview and explanation here:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime

`print(example.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))` will give you the right answer.

I would also look at the `arrow` library, as it offers a nice API to work with time.