# How to add a day to a formated date, without getting non standard dates like 30 February?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

How can I get the next date instead of today's date, should handle the month with 28 days like February. I don't want to get 32 December or 30 February :).

PS: sorry for my bad English, not my first language. Also, It's my first question.

**My code here:**

```
    def yeartoday(self):
        return datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y')

    def monthtoday(self):
        return datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%m')


    def daytoday(self):
        return datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%d')


    def informatdate1(self):
        return "%s-%s-%s" % (self.yeartoday(), self.monthtoday(), self.daytoday())


    def informatdate2(self):
        return "%s|%s|%s" % (self.yeartoday(), self.monthtoday(), self.daytoday())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `timedelta` from here https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html

you can just do `datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(1)`

EDIT to answer comment

you can still format it like you were doing before with `strftime`:

`my_new_time_var = (datetime.datetime.now()+timedelta(1)).strftime('%y|%m|%d')`

Comment: how to get that in format like 2019|11|15 and 2019-11-15?

Answer (score 0):

You need `timedelta`:

```
from datetime import timedelta,datetime
datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: how to get that in format like 2019|11|15 and 2019-11-15?

Comment: @raulnasper look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624937/convert-datetime-object-to-a-string-of-date-only-in-python