# How to convert datetime from tkcalendar to string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm creating a program that gets a date from users and now I need to convert to string 'cause I need to put this data into a command shell that I'm implementing, with tkinter and tkcalendar (that lib provides me to get entry).
How can I do that?

Here the code that I'm building to run on git:

```
cal = Calendar(top, font='Arial 14', selectmode='day', cursor='hand1')
subprocess.call('git log --pretty='"format: % h"' --after=' +cal+' --before='+cal, shell=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert datetime object to a String of date only in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624937/convert-datetime-object-to-a-string-of-date-only-in-python)

Comment: @wjandrea I tried and this was the exception from terminal:
```Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "window.py", line 29, in calendar
    cal.strtime('%Y/%m/%d')+' --before='+cal.strtime('%Y/%m/%d'), shell=True)
AttributeError: 'Calendar' object has no attribute 'strtime'```

Comment: You need to use the `datetime` attribute of the `Calendar` object, and then it's `strftime`, not `strtime`

Comment: Sorry about that but, looks that: ```Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "window.py", line 28, in calendar
    subprocess.call('git log --pretty='"format: % h"' --after=' + cal.datetime.strftime(
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object```

Answer (score 0):

In your case cal is a `Calendar` instance and `cal.datetime` returns python's `datetime` object which has `strftime` to format datetime to string:

```py
dt = cal.datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
subprocess.call(f"""git log --pretty="format: %h" --after={dt} --before={dt}""", shell=True)
```

Comment: The problem its I'm using Calendar lib, I won't to change this. How do I convert from the Calendar?