# Copy data-frame date index into a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame `df` with a head that looks like:

```
                                 amount_1  ...  factor
date                                       ...
2014-04-21                     931.550533  ...   100.0
2014-04-22                     932.174195  ...   100.0
2014-04-23                     946.622481  ...   100.0
2014-04-24                     938.722707  ...   100.0
2014-04-25                     949.325041  ...   100.0
```

I would like to take the index (`date`) and create a list.  I am using:

```
dates = df.index.map(pd.Timestamp.date).tolist()
```

which gives me an output:

```
[datetime.date(2014, 2, 21), datetime.date(2014, 2, 22), datetime.date(2014, 2, 23), datetime.date(2014, 2, 24), datetime.date(2014, 2, 25), .....]
```

However I would like the output to look like:

```
[2014-04-21,2014-04-22,2014-04-23,2014-04-24,2014-04-25,....]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert datetime object to a String of date only in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624937/convert-datetime-object-to-a-string-of-date-only-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

If want `YYYY-MM-DDDD` in strings use [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
dates = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-Yd')
```

If want remove times, it means set to `00:00:00` use [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html):

```
dates = df.index.floor('d')
```

Your solution should be changed use [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html):

```
dates = df.index.date
```