# Python convert datetime to date

Tags: python, datetime

I have following code that gives output as "**2020-07-30 15:59:17.535228**", I would like to convert it from datetime into year and month format "**20JUL**" using python

I understand this is possible, I tried all possible changes but each time I'm getting some or other error...

Can you please guide..

**Desired Output of below Python Code**

```
20JUL
```

**Python Code**

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta, TH

todayte = datetime.today()
cmon = todayte.month

for i in range(1, 6):
    t = todayte + relativedelta(weekday=TH(i))
    if t.month != cmon:
        # since t is exceeded we need last one  which we can get by subtracting -2 since it is already a Thursday.
        t = t + relativedelta(weekday=TH(-2))
        break
import datetime
print(t)
thu = datetime.datetime.strptime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').strftime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
print(thu)
```

**The Code is giving following error**

```
2020-07-30 15:59:17.535228
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NextExpiryDatetry.py", line 138, in <module>
    tame = datetime.datetime.strptime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').strftime(date, '%Y%M')
TypeError: strptime() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Read about [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) works.

Comment: `thu = todayte.strftime("%y%b")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert datetime object to a String of date only in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624937/convert-datetime-object-to-a-string-of-date-only-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta, TH

todayte = datetime.today()
cmon = todayte.month

for i in range(1, 6):
    t = todayte + relativedelta(weekday=TH(i))
    if t.month != cmon:
        # since t is exceeded we need last one  which we can get by subtracting -2 since it is already a Thursday.
        t = t + relativedelta(weekday=TH(-2))
        break
import datetime
print(t)
thu = todayte = datetime.today().strftime("%y%b")
print(thu)
```

This must give required output

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
month = now.month
day = now.day

# a list so you can easily index it
months = [
    "JAN",
    "FEB",
    "MAR",
    "APR",
    "MAY",
    "JUN",
    "JUL",
    "AUG",
    "SEP",
    "OCT",
    "NOV",
    "DEC"
]
print(
    str(day) + months[month - 1] # -1 since the Index starts at 0
)
```