# Convert datetime format to "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" string in Python

Tags: python, selenium, datetime

I am extracting date from Sql Query executed using selenium Python. The date variable shows up as `datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 27, 4, 16, 33)`
and I need to change the format in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS". Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert datetime object to a String of date only in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624937/convert-datetime-object-to-a-string-of-date-only-in-python)

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to change a datetime variable to string with specific format. It has nothing to do with SQL and Selenium

Comment: I am trying to fetch the data using sql from DB in my selenium python project but while printing the data the datetime format is coming as "datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 27, 4, 16, 33)" but I want this date to be retrieved as "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 27, 4, 16, 33)

x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

it returns

```
'2020-08-27 04:16:33'
```