# Can I execute a function stored into variable in python dictionaries?

Tags: python

I have a function stored into variable and I would like to execute that one into dictionary. Is it possible in Python?

```python
import datetime
x = datetime.date(2021, 8, 23)
item = {
    "dt": x
}
print(item)
```

**Obtained result:**
{'dt': datetime.date(2021, 8, 23)}

**Wanted result:**
{'dt': '2021-08-23'}

How to do?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you want a string as the end result why are you creating a datetime object: `x = datetime.date(2021, 8, 23)`?

Comment: You don't have a _function_ stored in the dictionary. You have a `datetime.date` object. When you print this object, its representation shows up as `datetime.date(...)`. To print a formatted date, format it using `strftime()`. If you don't want an object and only want to save the string in the first place, do that.

Comment: You can check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624937/convert-datetime-object-to-a-string-of-date-only-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are printing is the pre-defined __ repr __ function of datetime, not a string as you expected. So to keep it short, if you want to print it as a string as your requirement, try this (assuming you do not need to keep datetime data type in the dictionary)

```
import datetime
x = datetime.date(2021, 8, 23)
item = {
    "dt": x.strftime("%y-%m-%d")
}
print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for your desired result:

```
import datetime

x = datetime.date(2021, 8, 23)

item = {
    "dt": str(x)
}
```

Converting the date to a string solves the problem you are facing.