# Replacing string text in python w/ regex, re, or str.replace

Tags: python, regex

Hi I'm looking for some help replacing a certain string pattern in my data.  I have a massive list of json data from an API, however, it appears a date field is being returned as a python function before having been parsed out into raw text.  Below is an example of the `started_at` attribute in the raw json data which is causing me problems:

`'started_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 7, 16, 37, 26)`

Like instead of the actual date + timestamp in raw text, it's just represented as the python function.  When I try running json.loads() on this data, it fails because of this attribute not being properly parsed out.  So my potential solution is I want to replace the `datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 7, 16, 37, 26)` text with a simple variable like `current_date = str(datetime.now().date())`, so it will just be `2022-02-07` instead of the whole datetime string.

I've tried doing `raw_json.replace(datetime.datetime(*, *, *, *, *, *), current_date)`, but it doesn't work because I'm not sure how to manipulate the regex in a way so that it captures ANY pattern in that format.

Putting in some reproducible code below if anybody wants to try it out:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

current_date = str(datetime.now().date())
sample_json = str({'started_at': 'datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 7, 16, 37, 26)'})


formatted_json = sample_json.replace('datetime.datetime(*, *, *, *, *, *)', current_date)
```

Comment: Instead of `str`, use the `strftime` method to convert the datetime object to a string. You don't need a regex.

Comment: And use `json` module to convert a Python dictionary to a proper JSON string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert datetime object to a String of date only in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624937/convert-datetime-object-to-a-string-of-date-only-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enough trial & error I got the proper regex answer.

```
# all json text needs to be wrapped in double quotes
current_date = str(f'"{datetime.now().date()}"') 
sample_json = str({'started_at': 'datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 7, 16, 37, 26)'})
formatted_json = re.sub('datetime.datetime[\(\[].*?[\)\]]', current_date, sample_json)
```

The `[\(\[].*?[\)\]]` part will remove the parantheses and everything inside the parantheses, and adding in datetime.datetime will add that part to the string pattern as well.