# Get Date in specified format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to get today's `date` and `n` - today's `date` in the format below : -

```
tod = datetime.datetime.now()
d = datetime.timedelta(days = 365)
x = tod - d
```

I want `x` and `tod` in YYYYMMDD format for eg : 20230130
How do I get it to this format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `datetime` class has an `strftime` function that allows you to convert a datetime to string in the format you set (more info here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

```
import datetime
tod = datetime.datetime.now()
d = datetime.timedelta(days = 365)
x = tod - d
print(x.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
```

output:

```
20230130
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
tod = datetime.datetime.now()
d = datetime.timedelta(days = 365)
x = tod - d

#Before formatting
#print(d) #365 days, 0:00:00
#print(x) #2022-01-30 05:59:48.328091

#strftime can be used to format as your choice %Y for year, %m for month, %d for date

tod_ = tod.strftime("%Y%m%d")
x_ = x.strftime("%Y%m%d")

print(tod_) #20230130
print(x_)   #20220130
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar answer is here [Convert datetime object to a String of date only in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624937/convert-datetime-object-to-a-string-of-date-only-in-python).
It use `datetime.datetime.strftime` method to work.
For example in your case:

```
import datetime
tod = datetime.datetime.now()
d = datetime.timedelta(days = 365)
x = tod - d
print(x.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```