# Python datetime to string

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert this:

```
  my_time = datetime.datetime.now()
  my_datetime = my_time.strftime("%Y%M%D.%H%M%S")
```

To this:

```
'20235409.105400'
```

Instead I am getting this:

```
'20235409/25/23.105400'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `my_time.strftime("%Y%m%d.%H%M%S")`

Comment: Also, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35780962/21144042).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert datetime object to a String of date only in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624937/convert-datetime-object-to-a-string-of-date-only-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most certainly mean

```py
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d.%H%M%S")
```

Your initial code use `%M` (meaning minutes) instead of `%m` (month). And your example also does! (202354 is quite unrealistic).

And more importantly you used `%D` (meaning compact date in format `09/25/23`) instead of `%d` (day of month).